# For the one o'clock meeting or one o'clock meeting?

Tags: articles

1. Are you prepared for one o'clock meeting with the board members?
2. Are you prepared for *the* one o'clock meeting with the board members?

Both sound right to me. No2 has an article for "one o'clock meeting"

Is there a subtle difference between 1 and 2?

Comment: The difference is that 1) is not grammatical.

Comment: Interesting, because I got no1 from a TOEIC textbook and I added "the" to make it sound better and made that no2. Since I am not good with articles, I kinda gave the textbook the benefit of the doubt and assumed it was right. Anyway, thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Are you prepared for **a** one o'clock meeting with the board members? [if there is a meeting]

2) Are you prepared for **the** one o'clock meeting with the board members? [that specific meeting]

There must be an article before the time adjective here.

Comment: That logic does not work if, instead of just a meeting, one was talking about the annual conference of a political party or trade union. In that context one would hear "Are you prepared for Conference?".  I would never say it, because I agree that an article is needed, but that is actually the norm.

Comment: @JeremyC That is not  relevant to a time used as an adjective followed by a noun.  Here, we are looking at times on a clock + the word meeting.